# How to redirect nant build errors to 'catch' section?

Tags: nant

I need to build my application in 'try-catch' section of nant config file, like this:

```
<trycatch>
        <try>
         <echo message="Start building MyApplication.."/>
         <call target="BuildApp"/>
        </try>
        <catch>
         <echo message="Build MyApp.sln is failed"/>
         <fail/>
        </catch>
</trycatch>
```

When build is failed it only shows the message: "Build MyApp.sln is failed", without any detailed information why it failed. How can I redirect build errors to 'catch' section and see the reason of failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `property` attribute to the `catch` tag:

```
<trycatch>
  <try>
    <echo message="Start building MyApplication.."/>
    <call target="BuildApp"/>
  </try>
  <catch property="failure.message">
    <echo message="Build MyApp.sln is failed"/>
    <echo message="Failure message: ${failure.message}"/>
    <fail />
  </catch>
</trycatch>
```

You could also forward the failure message via `<fail message="${failure.message}" />`.